# ImportError: No module named bootstrap3 even while using virtualenv

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

After installing bootstrap3 by

```
$ pip install django-bootstrap3
```

while my `virtualenv` was active. i.e.

`(venv)deathstroke@Batcomputer:~/Documents/DjangoProjects/venv/bin$ pip install django-bootstrap3`

However, the following error is given -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/deathstroke/Documents/DjangoProjects/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/deathstroke/Documents/DjangoProjects/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/deathstroke/Documents/DjangoProjects/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/deathstroke/Documents/DjangoProjects/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/deathstroke/Documents/DjangoProjects/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 119, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named bootstrap3
```

when I run `import bootstrap3` in the shell, it works.

Why doesn't my Django app find or recognize it?

Comment: How are you running Django?

Comment: I'm not sure what 'running' Django means. Can you be more specific? I installed Django from the requirements.txt file and am running it from the command line, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Are you running the development server via `python manage.py runserver`?

Comment: Yes, I am. And not just runserver, this error is thrown when I execute any command of `manage.py`.

Comment: Which Django and Python version are you using?

Comment: Django == 1.8.0. With Python2.7

Comment: not sure if this helps, i had the exact same problem with another module a month ago or so, i don't remember, but it was either a broken django installation or a broken environment, i was using pyvenv thou.

Edit: now i remember, it was a broken django download, and the pip kept using the cached django download each time i tried to initiate the virtual environment, so i had to ``pip install --ignore-installed``, but the module wasn't a 3rd party module, it was something inside django built-ins

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently the `INSTALLED APPS` included `'django_admin_bootstrapped.bootstrap3'` which was not recognized and raised the error. I replaced this with simply `'bootstrap3',` and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I confirm that this was my problem as well. The instructions for django-admin-bootstrap module say that we should add the django_admin_bootstrapped.bootstrap3.

Answer (score 0):

run below command

```
pip install django-bootstrap3
```

and add bootstrap3 in INSTALLED APPS

for info go to below [pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap3](https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap3/)