# Django Bootstrap error

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

Related: [ImportError: No module named bootstrap3 even while using virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29781872/importerror-no-module-named-bootstrap3-even-while-using-virtualenv)

Every time I attempt to use manage.py (startapp, shell, etc) or load my page (using Apache), I get the error below. I'm running Django 1.8 inside a virtual environment, and already installed django-bootstrap-toolkit (and tried with django-bootstrap as well although I'm not sure what the difference is). The instructions on github said to add 'bootstrap3' to INSTALLED_APPS, which I did, and now get the following error:

```
...
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named bootstrap3
```

My Versions:

```
Django 1.8
Python 2.7.5
django-bootstrap-toolkit 2.15.0
```

from settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'bootstrap3',
    'django_cron',
```

What am I missing here? Thanks for your time.

Edit: Full pip freeze output:

```
(venv)[root@ myhost path]# pip freeze
IPy==0.75
PyOpenGL==3.0.1
SSSDConfig==1.12.2
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2 
blivet==0.61.0.27
chardet==2.2.1
configobj==4.7.2
configshell-fb==1.1.14
coverage==3.6b3                       
cupshelpers==1.0
decorator==3.4.0
di==0.3
django-bootstrap-toolkit==2.15.0    
dnspython==1.11.1
ethtool==0.8
firstboot==19.5                       
freeipa==2.0.0.alpha.0
fros==1.0
glusterfs-api==3.6.0.29
iniparse==0.4
initial-setup==0.3.9.23
iotop==0.6
ipaplatform==4.1.0
ipapython==4.1.0
javapackages==1.0.0
kerberos==1.1
kitchen==1.1.1
kmod==0.1
langtable==0.0.13
lxml==3.2.1
meld==3.11.0
netaddr==0.7.5
nose==1.3.0
numpy==1.7.1
pcp==1.0
policycoreutils-default-encoding==0.1
psutil==1.2.1
psycopg2==2.5.1
pyOpenSSL==0.13.1
pyasn1==0.1.6
pycups==1.9.63
pycurl==7.19.0
pygobject==3.8.2
pygpgme==0.3
pyinotify==0.9.4
pykickstart==1.99.43.17
pyliblzma==0.5.3
pyodbc==3.0.0-unsupported
pyparsing==1.5.6
pyparted==3.9
python-augeas==0.4.1
python-dateutil==1.5
python-default-encoding==0.1
python-dmidecode==3.10.13
python-ldap==2.4.15
python-meh==0.25.2
python-nss==0.16.0
python-yubico==1.2.1
pytz==2012d
pyudev==0.15
pyusb==1.0.0b1
pyxattr==0.5.1
qrcode==5.0.1
rtslib-fb==2.1.50
scdate==1.10.6
seobject==0.1
sepolicy==1.1
setroubleshoot==1.1
six==1.3.0
slip==0.4.0
slip.dbus==0.4.0
stevedore==0.14
targetcli-fb==2.1.fb37
urlgrabber==3.10
urwid==1.1.1
virtualenv==1.10.1
virtualenv-clone==0.2.4
virtualenvwrapper==4.3.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
yum-langpacks==0.4.2
yum-metadata-parser==1.1.4
```

Comment: What's in a pip freeze output?

Comment: Updated post to include. Most of it must be dependencies, I've only manually installed a few things.

Comment: I installed django inside the venv, but it's not listed.. is that common?

Comment: You have `django-bootstrap-toolkit==2.15.0`, however docs say, that you need `django-bootstrap3` package to use bootstrap3. Can it be the reason?

Comment: I may have gotten some wires crossed at some point, following various posts on the bootstrap instructions.. I'll double check, remove all existing bootstrap related packages and try again.. guess I can't see the forest for the trees.. ;)

Comment: @chem1st You got it -- if you want to convert the comment to an answer, I'd be glad to accept it. Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: glad to help you! Ckeck out the posted answer.

Comment: Your virtual environment was not created correctly to start with. You have packages installed that are bound to the system - not to mention you are missing django.  Please upgrade the version of virtualenv on your system, as the latest version creates a clean virtual environment for you (without any system-level Python modules - like `yum-langpacks` which you don't need).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is said in docs, you need `django-bootstrap3` package to use bootstrap3. Here is the [link](https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3).

Answer (score 0):

I defer to the answer above. Just pointing out that the django-bootstrap-toolkit, which is for v2 of Bootstrap, could be removed. Thanks for using these libraries!

Comment: Thanks, I realized that after noting the bootstrap/bootstrap3 difference. Not sure what was going on their with my brain, looking too closely I guess.